# WordPress hook "post_submitbox_misc_actions" not working

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hook

I am trying to add `Modified Date` field in `edit.php` file in backend admin panel and update its value with current date & time once post or page is updated. I have written following code but it is not working. It doesn't show any `Modified Date` field no matter how many times I update post or activate/deactivate the plugin. This is my first try writing plugin.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function add_modified_date_field() {
    echo '<div class="misc-pub-section custom-modified-date">';
    echo '<label for="modified_date">Modified Date:</label>';
    echo '<span id="modified_date">';
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Display the current date and time
    echo '</span></div>';
}

add_action('post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'add_modified_date_field');

function update_modified_date($post_id) {
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;

    if (get_post_type($post_id) === 'post' || get_post_type($post_id) === 'page') {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'custom_modified_date', current_time('mysql'));
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'update_modified_date');
```

Comment: You need to retrieve the custom modified date from the `post meta` and display it in the `add_modified_date_field` function.

add this line to your `add_modified_date_field` function

`$modified_date = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_modified_date', true);`

and modify line 4 to use this code

`echo $modified_date ? $modified_date : date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`